Why can't I read some of the "System Control Coprocessor"registers?
I develop this mobile phone program: https://github.com/userse31/brewit
Now, Qualcomm BREW doesn't have anything like /proc/cpuinfo, but I still want to get more information about the CPU's in these ancient phones! So what to do?
Answer: The System Control Processor!
So, this works! I'm able to get stuff like the CPU and CACHE ID. This is great! (Except for the fact this doesn't work on all phones because not all of them run user land programs in ring zero but SSSSSHHHHHH!)
But trying to fetch stuff like the Control bits or CP15 register 1, causes the phone to reset.
What gives? This is on an LG Voyager, and my program is running under "Supervisor" mode. Does the phone not support this feature? Or is this some sort of weird permissions issue?
Eg, "mrc p15, 0, r0, c2, c0, 0" on the phone in an attempt to read the Page Table Control registers crashes the phone.

Note that ARM doesn't have rings like x86, but rather exception levels and these work the other way round: user space code usually runs in exception level 0.

Huh. Interesting.

Granted, Qualcomm BREW doesn't really have privilege levels other then the CPU modes, so I used "ring 0" more as an allegory.

The question is, does the code run in EL0 (user mode) or EL1 (supervisor mode)?  If it runs in EL0, it's clear why you cannot read the registers.

It runs in EL1.

It was both me not being super familiar with ARM assembly and the phone not supporting certain features.
Example:
I wrote the instructions for fetching the control registers wrong.
What I did: mrc p15, 0, %0, c1, c1, 0
What I SHOULD of done: mrc p15, 0, %0, c1, c0, 0
Also, trying to fetch the auxiliary and coprocessor control registers crashes the phone. I'm guessing the CPU is just too old to have them.
